# how to create a list with random round values with a given max value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, random

I want to create a list with a length of 4

I have a df,

```
        contents    values
    0   A           484
    1   B           429
    2   C           130
    3   D           108
    4   E           77
    5   F           2
```

I want to define a bin range for these values.
I am trying to get a df in what range these values are lying
here, I have a max_value of 484.

```
  my_max=468, it should give round-off values in the list

  my desired output is, output_list=[0,100,300,500]
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: From excel sheet, I filtered the occurence of these values using value_counts() and now I am trying to get a list with a range of values for my binning

Comment: yes, I dont want 6 rows. I want to create a range with a length of 4

Comment: You want to generate bins automatically? As Zero said explain how did you arrive at the output list.

Comment: yes, that is unequal bin, I need a bin with equal difference, I gave that bin for example

Comment: @pyd -- you need ask your question clearly with expected output. Folks here assume your question as sacrosanct, it can't filled with holes like this. So, what according to you is equal difference bin example?

Comment: If the max value is 484, first ill round off it to 500, then if the length is 6
then my output_list should be [0,100,200,300,400,500]. let me know for any more information

Answer (score 1):

If you know that there are maximum of three digits, then you can use:

```
int(round(484,-2))
```

output:

```
=> 500
```

A generalization for this function is (replace `484` with value):

```
int(round(484,-(len(str(484))-1)))
```

output:

```
=> 500
```

Comment: `-2` should probably be a function of `484`. Otherwise, it's a promising function.

Comment: thank you, using this i can get round off, is this possible to get a list of range between (0,5) with a defined length

Comment: Added a generic function that should work for all values

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.linspace`

```
In [1212]: np.linspace(0, round(df['values'].max(), -2), len(df))
Out[1212]: array([   0.,  100.,  200.,  300.,  400.,  500.])
```

Comment: this one works fine, but we need to remove the (.) in each item